# Не могу понять, как на нативном JS получить JSON(лежит там же где и index.html)

Tags: javascript, json

Задача в том, чтоб без использования библиотек и фреймворков получить json, а дальше парсить его. Вопрос, как это сделать? Нашел вариант, где можно просто в html-ке его прописать типа вот так `<script type="text/javascript" src="source/questions.json"></script>` , но тогда вопрос как с ним работать в script.js ?

Comment: Получайте через ajax-запрос

Comment: Здесь очень подробно расписано: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Если не большой, можешь сделать `.js` файл `(json.js)` в котором присвоишь переменной `(let objJson)` свой `json` потом в `html` подключаешь этот файл раньше других скриптов `<script type="text/javascript" src="source/json.js"></script>` и можешь обращаться к переменной `objJson` в скриптах подключенных ниже...